# Data binding in library module

Tags: android, gradle, binding, module

I have project with two modules: library and example. Everything working fine since I would like to use data binding in my library module.

When I try to use class in example module with databinding usage app crashes with:

```
Caused by: java.lang.NoClassDefFoundError: Failed resolution of: 
Lcom/app/test/databinding/TextItemBinding;
```

I'm using `gradle 2.1.2` and also tested with `2.2.0-beta2`.

Both modules has import for:

```
dataBinding {
  enabled true
}
```

When I move my code of `DataBinding` to single module project code is working correctly.

Has anyone had similar problem?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Found resolution, I had:

```
testCoverageEnabled true
```

in `debug` section which was showing this error.