# Data binding errors in application module

Tags: android, data-binding, kotlin

I have an android library (kotlin) using data binding. The library itself compiles fine. When I add the library as a module onto another app I receive a large number of data binding errors, which seems to be all the data binding I am using in the library.

[image]

After researching the problem, many people have suggested adding

```
dataBinding {
   enabled = true
}
```

into both the app and library `build.gradle` file.

Even after doing this I still receive the same errors. I have tried cleaning the project multiple times with no changes. If anybody could explain why the library will build on its own as a separate project but will not build when included as a module in another project, I would be grateful.

app - build.gradle

```
apply plugin: 'com.android.application'
apply plugin: 'kotlin-android'
apply plugin: 'kotlin-android-extensions'
apply plugin: 'realm-android'
apply plugin: 'kotlin-kapt'

android {
    compileSdkVersion 26
    defaultConfig {
        applicationId "cz.abc.abc"
        minSdkVersion 19
        targetSdkVersion 26
        versionCode 1
        versionName "1.0"
    }


    buildTypes {
        release {
            minifyEnabled false
            proguardFiles getDefaultProguardFile('proguard-android.txt'), 'proguard-rules.pro'
            //signingConfig signingConfigs.release
        }
    }

    dataBinding {
        enabled = true
    }
}

dependencies {
    implementation fileTree(dir: 'libs', include: ['*.jar'])
    implementation 'com.android.support:appcompat-v7:26.1.0'
    implementation "org.jetbrains.kotlin:kotlin-stdlib-jre7:$kotlin_version"

    kapt "com.android.databinding:compiler:3.0.1"
    implementation 'android.arch.lifecycle:extensions:1.0.0'

    implementation project(':my-library')
}
```

library/module - build.gradle

```
apply plugin: 'com.android.library'
apply plugin: 'kotlin-android'
apply plugin: 'kotlin-android-extensions'
apply plugin: 'realm-android'
apply plugin: 'kotlin-kapt'

def AAVersion = '4.4.0-SNAPSHOT'
def supportVersion = "26.1.0"
def anko_version = "0.10.1"

android {
    compileSdkVersion 26
    buildToolsVersion "26.0.2"
    defaultConfig {
        minSdkVersion 19
        targetSdkVersion 26
        versionCode 1
        versionName "1.0"
        multiDexEnabled true
    }

    buildTypes {
        release {
            minifyEnabled false
            proguardFiles getDefaultProguardFile('proguard-android.txt'), 'proguard-rules.pro'
        }
    }

    packagingOptions {
        pickFirst 'META-INF/LICENSE.txt'
    }

    dataBinding {
        enabled = true
    }
}

kapt {
    correctErrorTypes = true
    generateStubs = true
}

dependencies {
    ...
    implementation "org.jetbrains.kotlin:kotlin-stdlib-jre7:$kotlin_version"
    kapt "com.android.databinding:compiler:+"
    ...
}
```

**Gradle Build Tools:** 3.0.1

**Kotlin:** 1.2.0

**EDIT**

I have changed the way of import. Instead of importing the library, and making copy of the library in the project, I have just put a path to the library in `setting.gradle`.

settings.gradle

```
include ':app'
include ':my-library'

project (':my-library').projectDir = new File('../library')
```

The error is differend now:

[image]

Comment: have look [this](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/39200465/data-binding-in-library-module)

Comment: @HemantParmar I've already seen that, don't have any testCoverageEnabled anywhere in my project

Comment: data binding errors hard to get. whenever we do silly mistake it shows app level errors. even me to work on data binding. try to check your code once and find out on your way.

Comment: try removing the `kapt {}` block from you gradle file.
also, `kapt "com.android.databinding:compiler:+"` is dangerous, since the compiler version needs to be the same as the android-gradle-plugin version.

Comment: @Lovis Thanks for advice, I changes the + to specific version. Removing kapt didnt help. The error remained the same, but I have changed the way of importing module an now I am getting different error.